# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datatables-1.10

Im unable to post question . Please see attached screen shot for error.

[image]

```html
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="num in numbers">
    <td> {{num.number}} </td>
    <td> {{num.short_description}} </td>
    <td> {{num.category}} </td>
    <td> {{num.subcategory}} </td>
    <td> {{num.priority}} </td>
    <td> {{num.urgency}} </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please see my code below.

Comment: <table class="table table-striped" id="my_incidents_details" border='1'>
           <tr>
          
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Short Description</td>
            <td>Category</td>
            <td>Sub Category</td>
            <td>Priority</td>
            <td>Urgency</td>
            
            </tr>

Comment: <tr ng-repeat="num in numbers">
   
        <td>  {{num.number}} </td> 
        <td>{{num.short_description}}</td>
        <td>  {{num.category}} </td> 
        <td>  {{num.subcategory}} </td> 
        <td>  {{num.priority}} </td> 
        <td>  {{num.urgency}} </td> 
     
            </tr>
            
             </table>

Comment: May be you can create a fiddle using https://jsfiddle.net/ and update your question with the link..

Comment: Thanks for quick response please see below URL.

https://jsfiddle.net/k6q6jmwh/

Comment: no , i didn't assign , but still i get this error .

Comment: Im just trying pagination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datatable requires table HTML in proper format, using `<thead>` and `<tbody>`
Also number of `<th>` and number of `<td>` in all row should match. (but colspan can be used in headers) 
Try this HTML -

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="my_incidents_details" border="1">
        <thead>
                <tr>
                         <th>Number</th>
                         <th>Short Description</th>
                         <th>Category</th>
                         <th>Sub Category</th>
                         <th>Priority</th>
                         <th>Urgency</th>
                </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>                     
          <tr ng-repeat="num in numbers">

                 <td>  {{num.number}} </td> 
                 <td>{{num.short_description}}</td>
                 <td>  {{num.category}} </td> 
                 <td>  {{num.subcategory}} </td> 
                 <td>  {{num.priority}} </td> 
                 <td>  {{num.urgency}} </td> 

                                             </tr>
            </tbody>                                 
</table>
```

Comment: This trick worked . Thank you all for your help . 
How to mark it as Correct answer ?